# VK API user.get()

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста. Не могу найти в документации, как получить основную информацию о пользователе на стороне сервера(php)? По типу как я в запросе указал **&scope=email** и мне вернуло json с email, id и токеном. Все говорят об **user.get()**, но этот метод, как я понял, работает только на js.

В фейсбуке можно сразу было указать **&scope=public_profile** и он возвращал основную информацию пользователя. В ВК такого не нашел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел. В ВК немного по другому это делается, надо делать отдельный запрос.

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52
```